# mediaelementplayer js not support to MOV video formats how can i play MOV video in mediaelementplayerjs

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, media-player, mediaelement.js

I am not able to play MOV format video in mediaelementplayer js how can i play that one video

```
<video class="hide_video<?php echo $key; ?> gettime" data-id="<?php echo $vd['chapterID'];?>" preload="none" rel='<?php echo $key; ?>' >
 <source class="playVideo" type="video/youtube" src="<?php echo $vd['videoUrl'];?>" />
</video>
```

Comment: Could you please adjust "video/youtube" to “video/mp4” and then check clear your Chrome browser cache and see if that helped

Comment: ho ka sachin sir.....let me chek it